# $\lim_{x \to 0^+} ({\sqrt{x}})^x =1$

Tags: real-analysis

I want to know why the following statement is true.

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} ({\sqrt{x}})^x =1$$

Can somebody give a proof for this please?

Comment: Is it possible that the intent is $\sqrt[x]{x}=x^\frac1x$?  Of course now the title does not match the body, which is correct?

Comment: You mean $x^{th}$ root of x?

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(\sqrt{x})^x=\infty\neq1$.

Comment: as stated in the question, this is not true. However, it seems that the title has been changed.  Should $o^+$ be $0^+$?

Comment: I'm really sorry guys my intent was limit of $x^{x/2}$ as x goes to $0^+$. I edited now. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @yhk, it is the same!:$$\left(\sqrt x\right)^x=x^{x/2}\;\ldots$$

Comment: Yeah. what is the point? That is what I meant. I changed from "$\infty$" to $"0^+"$. @DonAntonio

Comment: Then be clear: it looked like you thought you were changing the function, and two asnwer here below refer to the case $\;x\to 0^\;$ already...

Comment: Yes Sorry at first I made a mistake. But, As soon as I noticed it I changed it. And I think this is not a big problem to discuss here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking logs we get
$$
\log\left(x^{x/2}\right)=\frac x2\log(x)
$$
Using L'Hospital, we get that
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\log(x)}{2/x}
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{1/x}{-2/x^2}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}-x/2\\
&=0
\end{align}
$$
Since $e^x$ is continuous at $0$, we get that
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0^+}x^{x/2}
&=e^{\ \large\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\frac x2\log(x)}\\
&=e^0\\
&=1
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 3):

We have:

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^x=\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{x\log\left(\sqrt{x}\right)}=\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{\frac{x}{2}\log\left(x\right)}=\infty.
$$

Since: $\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{t}=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}x\log x=\infty$

And we have:

$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^x=\lim_{x\to0^+}e^{x\log\left(\sqrt{x}\right)}=\lim_{x\to0^+}e^{\frac{x}{2}\log\left(x\right)}=1.
$$

Since: $e^{0}=1$ and $\lim_{x\to0^+}x\log x=0$

Comment: Just rewriting it as $x^{x/2}$ is sufficient to prove that it goes to $\infty$, without invoking logarithms.

Comment: Thank you very much. @حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع

Comment: I'm really sorry guys my intent was limit of $x^{x/2}$ as x goes to $0^+$. I edited now. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

$x^x = e^{xlnx} \to e^{-x} \to 1$, as $x \to 0$, by L'hopital rule. I think you mean limit as $x \to 0$ and not $\infty$.

Comment: How are you applying L'Hopital?

Comment: $xlnx = \dfrac{lnx}{\dfrac{1}{x}}$

Comment: Good. If that were in your answer, it would be better.